# Meteor - Create a new folder in the public directory on account creation

Tags: javascript, meteor, filesystems

I'm working on a meteor project and one of its functionality is for users to upload their pictures in their profile. I wanted to create a new folder in the public directory (i.e public/img/user_id/files_to_upload_here.jpg), every time a new user is created.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    //code to create a folder
});
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to go. Use a filesystem like CollectionFS instead:

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly use the function from the node API:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = './directory';

fs.mkdirSync(dir);
```

[Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode)

You also have the async method which do the same.

Comment: Can't figure out how to make it work. Here's my new code: var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    var dir = '/public/users/newfolder';
    fs.mkdirSync(dir); but it returns me an error 'no such file or directory'.

Comment: delete Npm in front of require, you forgot the dot. in front of the slash... the given code work fine if you copy paste...